# How do I find which Microsoft product a license key is for?

Tags: licensing

I'm sorting out all our software and licenses and I have a few empty disc sleeves from the Microsoft Action Pack which have a valid key on them but no disc, meaning there is no indication which product the key is for.

Given a Microsoft product key, is there anyway to look it up to see what product it is for?

Comment: That's odd.  Usually it says in small letters what the product is for..

Comment: Most ways of getting software keys put the product with a key, but in MAPs a lot of the keys are orange stickers on the CD sleeves that do not name the product, so if you ever mix up the discs you're in trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm affraid it's impossible. You can only try to apply it to products you have (in newer software made by Microsoft there is option *change product key*; when key does not work nothing will happen). If you may have applied it the serial is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProductKey`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll put them aside and if my audit finds software we don't have a key for I'll see if those are the ones. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try entering the key into the Product Keys section of the [Volume Activation Management Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=11936)

I'm not certain that it works for ALL license keys, but I know it works for all volume license keys, and I just tried it on an OEM Windows 7 sticker key, and it was able to return the product and edition.

Comment: Sadly it does not. YOu can use your brain if you find alternative numbers - SOME Products have different format, but as long as the "look" (number of characters) is identical, and VAMT does not trigger (and it only handles IIRC Windows and newer Office) you are out of luck.